# Bootstrap - Set properly active class on navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

This is my `base.html.twig` template, where I have a navbar. I have a problem setting the active class on the clicked elements of the navbar.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" {{asset ('public/css/jquery.dataTables.css')}}">
        <link href="{{asset ('public/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href= "{{asset ('public/css/starter-template.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="{{ asset ('public/js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="{{ asset ('public/js/jquery.dataTables.js') }}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="{{ asset ('public/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="{{ asset ('public/js/myscript.js') }}"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="">App</a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active">
            <a href = "{{path('customers')}}" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#customers">Customers</a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href = "{{path('sellers')}}" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sellers"">Sellers</a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href = "{{path('news')}}" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#news">News</a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href = "{{path('about')}}" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#about"">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href = "#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#import">Import</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
        </nav>
        {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

This is the `myscript.js` included in the template that I use to set the `active` class on navbar elements:

```
    $(".nav a").on("click", function(){
    $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    });
```

Why is not working? Thanks!

**EDIT**

It seems it's because of the paths defined in the `<a>` element. Having a list without paths, the js works. Any idea on how to make it work with paths?

**EDIT 2 - How I solved**

Thanks everyone for the help, finally I solved using this code in twig:

```
{% set route = app.request.attributes.get('_route') %}
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li {{ route ==  'customers' ? 'class="active"' }}>
        <a href = "{{path('customers')}}" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#clienti">Customers</a>
        </li>
        <li {{ route ==  'sellers' ? 'class="active"' }}>
        <a href = "{{path('sellers')}}" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#venditori">Sellers</a>
        </li>
        <li {{ route ==  'news' ? 'class="active"' }}>
        <a href = "{{path('news')}}" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#news">News</a>
        </li>
        <li {{ route ==  'about' ? 'class="active"' }}>
        <a href = "{{path('about')}}" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#suggerimenti">About</a>
        </li>
     </ul>
```

Comment: You ensure your js script is set properly footer or header?

Comment: The js seems to work fine: http://www.bootply.com/0CcoAAXeGu Are you sure it's not because it's navigating to another page?

Comment: @illeas yes, as you can see, my script is in the header

Comment: @ZimSystem After another check, It seems you're right. it's because of the paths defined in href.

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```
 $('li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The links are not working. If I comment the e.preventDefault(); line, the links are working, but the active class it's not.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(".nav").on("click","a", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).closest('li').addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this may help you

`$(".nav li a").on("click", function(){ 
    $(".nav").find(".active").removeAttr("class");
    $(this).parent().attr("class","active");
    });`

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to remove all the active class from the nav and just add active to the current a

```
jQuery('.nav li').On(click, function({
   jQuery('.nav li').removeClass('active');
   jQuery(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(document).on("click",".nav a", function(){
 $(".nav").find("li").removeClass("active");
 $(this).closest("li").addClass("active");
});
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate. I edited the question with the solution.